# Can we view a log analytics alert in azure using azure cli or powershell?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

We can create/update/view **Classic log analytics alerts** in azure through azure powershell or cli. Can we create/update/view a normal **alert** in log analytics using azure cli or powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, the CLI functions to do that aren't released yet. The functionality should be released soon. They're moving log analytics alerts into the new Azure Security Insights.

There's a [rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-api-alerts) that is able to edit alerts, but it can't edit saved searches, so it's useless for updating the queries.